# I would like to remove the first n colors from a colormap without losing the original number of colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colormap

```
from matplotlib import cm
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Here is the original colormap

```
cmap = [cm.inferno(x)[:3] for x in range(0,256)]
sns.palplot(cmap)
```

[image]

My preferred outcome is something along the lines the colormap shown below, **except** with original number of colours

```
cmap2 = [cm.inferno(x)[:3] for x in range(0,256)][100:]
sns.palplot(cmap2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that by "same resolution" you mean that you want 256 colors in the palette. I would actually think of this as having a different resolution from the original palette in sense that the values are closer together in the color space. In any case, I think you can get what you want by doing:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import cm

x = np.linspace(.3, 1, 256)
pal = cm.inferno(x)
sns.palplot(pal)
```

[image]